# Delete image from array on click with php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

How can I delete an image from the database when user clicks it.

I have an input field that places the image links into a table with each link separated with a comma..

```
<input id="galleryImgs" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]">
```

This is how the array of images looks in the post_gallery_img database column.

Img1.jpg,Img2.jpg,Img3.jpg,Img4.jpg,

I am calling the images from the database and showing them with this php code.

```
$query = "SELECT post_gallery_img FROM posts WHERE post_id = $get_post_id";
$select_gallery_imgs = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_gallery_imgs)) {
    $post_gallery_img = $row['post_gallery_img'];

    $post_gallery_img = explode(',', $row['post_gallery_img']);

    foreach($post_gallery_img as $out) {
       echo '<img id="editPostGalleryImgs" src="../userImages/' . $out . '" alt="Post Image">';
    }
}
```

This is how it looks to the user[image]

Now my goal is to let the user click the second Image and have it be deleted from the array and when "Update Post" is clicked the post_gallery_img column is updated with new array.

I have an update query looking something like this.

```
$implodeArray = implode(',', array_filter($post_gallery_img));

$query = "UPDATE posts SET post_gallery_img = CONCAT('{$implodeArray}' , ',') WHERE post_id = $get_post_id ";

$delete_img = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could remove the image from PHP and then update the field in the database with the new value:

```
<?php
$before = "image1,image2,image3,image4";
$image_to_remove = $_GET['image_to_delete'];
$images_list = explode(",", $before);
$new_images_list = array();
foreach($images_list as $img){
    if($img == $image_to_remove){
        continue;
    }
    $new_images_list[] = $img;
}
$after = implode(",", $new_images_list);

$query = "UPDATE posts SET post_gallery_img = '$after' WHERE post_id = $get_post_id ";
```

The previous code is not a stable version, you have to adapt it to your needs.

**UPDATE:** Look at the update I did, now you can get the image to delete using the global variable $_GET.

If you create a link like this...

```
<a href="some.php?image_to_delete=YOUR_IMAGE_NAME">Remove image</a>
```

... Yo will receive in $_GET['image_to_delete'] the name of the image to delete.

Comment: How does this get the specific image the user clicked to remove?

Comment: You could get the image using the global variable $_GET. I will update my previous code for show you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can do that with some jQuery.

1. Put the images and 'Update Post' button in a form.
2. Add hidden checkboxes to the form, one for each image. Set the value property of the checkbox to be the same as the image names - Img1.jpg, Img2.jpg, etc. Set all checkboxes default to 'checked'
3. Add a jQuery click handler for the images so that: when an image is clicked, it's corresponding hidden checkbox will be unchecked.
4. When the form is submitted, get the values of the checkboxes and update your post_gallery_img field.